# Program should read from a file and returns a dictionary but returning a type error

Tags: python, dictionary

The dataset looks like this-

```
Action|10|Golden Tree (2012)
Drama|3|Titanic (1967)
```

So it is `Genre|SerialNo|Movie`

Required output is-

```
{ "Toy Story (1995)" : "Adventure", "Golden Tree (2012)" : "Action" }
```

Currently, the only output generated is "Action", I tried to write some code to fix it, but returns a type error. How do I fix this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_genre_data(file):  
    movie_genre_dict  = {}
    ratings = defaultdict(list)
    for line in open(file):
        genre, num, movie  = line.split('|')
        #movie[genre].append(movie)   
    return genre
readGenre = read_genre_data("genreMovieSample.txt")
print(readGenre)
```

Comment: You're not adding anything to the dictionary.

Comment: You need to add to the dictionary in the loop, and then return the dictionary at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the dictionary, and then return the dictionary. You're just returning the value of `genre` from the last line of the file.

```
def read_genre_data(file):  
    movie_genre_dict  = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            genre, num, movie  = line.split('|')
            movie_genre_dict[movie] = genre
        return movie_genre_dict
```

Comment: Might suggest expanding the answer to use a ```with``` block so the file gets closed, just for completeness.

Comment: I added it, although the garbage collector will automatically close the file when the function returns.

Comment: Still a good habit to be in - GC isn't guaranteed to run immediately.

Comment: True, although for an input file it doesn't really matter. It's more important for output files, since closing flushes the buffers.